# Add vector to every column of matrix

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Say I have a matrix:

```
[a1 b1 ...]
[a2 b2 ...]
[a3 b3 ...]
[.. .. ...]
```

And a vector:

```
[d1 d2 d3 ...]
```

How could I get:

```
[a1+d1 b1+d1 ...]
[a2+d2 b2+d2 ...]
[a3+d3 b3+d3 ...]
[.. .. .. .. ...]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the original matrix is $M$ and the vector is $v$, then the matrix you want is $M+[1\ 1\ 1\ \ldots\ 1]^t\cdot v$.

Comment: Is there a name for the process of doing `[1 1 1 … 1]t⋅v`? Or anything such a function might be called that does this?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  It's not that often that people need to do something like this...